# Access to fetch at 'my-url' from origin 'http://www.mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the cors policy error like this.

```
Access to fetch at 'my-url' from origin 'http://www.mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This is my code:

```
const requestOptionsBR = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            action: "user_reports",
            user_id: this.state.user_id,
            start_date: this.convertDate(this.state.startDate),
            end_date: this.convertDate(this.state.endDate),
        }),
    };


    fetch(my-url, requestOptionsBR)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ loadingStatus: true });
            console.log("User Reports", data)
            if (data.status) {
                this.setState({
                    user_data: data.params,
                    loadingStatus: false,
                    resultRetrieved: true,
                });
                this.generate_download_csv_data(data.params);
            }
```

The above is working fine in local , but in production it is not working.
How to overcome this issue?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard `*` isn't allowed, as you must give a specific protocol, domain and port for security reasons.

More info here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

As the error message suggests, you can also set the option:

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```

...in your `requestOptionsBR`, however this will limit what you can put in your request headers.

More info here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

Comment: Both the solutions i have tried , It does'nt work